# retrieve the height of a table in Firefox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dynamic table with height 300 px and overflow-y: scroll such that table will have a vertical scroller. If there are less rows I want to change the height of the table so that there will be no space in the table and a scroll.

I was trying to retrieve the height of the table but it comes as 0. when I looked into the trace I can see that element has height. I tried

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height  
document.getElementById("myDiv").offsetHeight  
document.getElementById("myDiv").clientHeight
```

but none of them return a valid value to height.

here is my Css:

```
.tableSroll {    
    overflow: auto;    
}  
.myDiv {  
    display: block;  
    width: 900px;  
    height: 300px;  
    overflow:auto;  
    overflow-y: scroll;  
}  

.ai-table-list-items {  
    pading: 50px;  
    width: 100%;  
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="tableScroll">

    <div class= "myDiv" id= "myDiv" >  

         <table class="ai-table-list-items">.....</table>  

    </div>  

</div>
```

can anybody please help me to retrieve the height of the div in Firefox? I have been searching for it since a long time..

Thanks in advance,
Pbale

Comment: Can you use jQuery or does it have to be vanilla JavaScript? jQuery's `.height()` function may come in useful.

Comment: works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/MQcrR/

Comment: this isn't your main problem, but you mis-typed `padding`

Comment: Is the Javascript running before the `div` is loaded in the document?  Or before you add content somehow?

Comment: no. Javascript runs after the Div is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Change `class` to `id` for simplicity:

```
<div id="tableScroll">
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('tableScroll').style.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `jQuery` often greatly simplifies the development. Using it, you can achieve your goals by:

```
$(#tableId).height();
```

Comment: I can't use the JQuery. It has to be in Javascript.

Comment: @user1588142 Then wanovak's answer should suit you. :)